# Input Error estimation

Tags: reference-request, error-propagation

I was wondering what are the methods used to detect the input's error when having the  output's error of a model.

I thoroughly searched on google, but I  failed to find a well explined method,  or even a reference of the subject!

Would some one help me finding some references or some methods under this title. This help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like [backward error analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_analysis_%28mathematics%29#Backward_error_analysis)?
It should be treated in most introductions to numerical analysis or scientific computation.

Comment: @gammatester yes  in this manner.